# ngFor="Lets" loads all the code with no error but leave page blank

Tags: angular

When I am trying to run bootstrap for ngFor but the ngFor function leaves page blank

Please find my code below.

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>Primary Members</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let member of member" class="col-md-6">
                <member-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(member.name)" [member]="member"></member-thumbnail>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
```

Comment: What is the name of the array that you want to iterate through? Seems like there is an error at 'let member of member' in the ngFor statement.

Comment: im exporting from a class 

export class MembersListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public member:IMember;

    constructor(private memberService: MemberService, private toastr: ToastrService, private route:ActivatedRoute){
        
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.member = this.route.snapshot.data['members']
    }

    handleThumbnailClick(memberName){
        this.toastr.success(memberName)
    }
}

Comment: Try renaming the array (e.g. members) and then change the ngFor statement to 'let member of members'

Comment: member is an array from IMember created through member.service.ts which exports from member.service.ts

Comment: Make up yur mind. Either it's an array, and it should be named `members`, with a final s to make it clear it contains several members, and be of type `IMember[]`and not `IMember`, or it's a single member, and the route data should be named `member` and not `members`, and you shouldn't use an ngFor to display it.

Comment: Then use your debugger, or console.log(), to see what `this.route.snapshot.data['members'] ` actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

If the first member is an array then try

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>Primary Members</h1>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let item of member" class="col-md-6">
                <member-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(item.name)" [member]="item"></member-thumbnail>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
```

OR

@Component({
        template: 
        `<div>
            <h1>Primary Members</h1>
            <hr/>
            <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor="let item of member; let i = index" class="col-md-6">
                    <member-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(member[i].name)" [member]="member[i]"></member-thumbnail>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

    })

Answer (score -1):

Could you please use before and after '' inside your DOM

```
@Component({ template:' 
<div>
    <h1>Primary Members</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let member of member" class="col-md-6">
            <member-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(member.name)" [member]="member"></member-thumbnail>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'
})
```